# HTTPClient Post Request with Headers and Body

Tags: c#, http, web, httpclient

I want to set the Content-Type and Authorization Headers using HttpClient and want to load the xml file for the body(request) and send Post request.

I have searched for combining both headers and body for Post request.

Setting up the Headers using HttpRequestMessage.

```cs
HttpClient clientTest = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,url);

httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.citrix.sessionparams+xml");
httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("CitrixAuth", "H4sIAAAAAAAEAK1X2Y6jyBL9lZLnEbnZt1J");
```

Setting the xml body -

```cs
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("RequestSession.xml");
```

Converting to Document.ToString()

```cs
var httpContent = new StringContent(xml.Document.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.citrix.sessionstate+xml");
```

Please help me with combining both headers and body for Post Request using HttpClient.

Comment: All you need to do is send the `HttpRequestMessage`. I don't understand what you mean by "*combine*":  `var response = await clientTest.SendAsync(httpRequest);`

Comment: Crowcoder - Thanks for the response. I have both headers and body for the post request. You are sending the headers for the request - httpRequest object.  But I have a body - Requessession.xml I need to send this too for PostAsync.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. You set headers. You set body. You send the request. Please explain the problem better.

Comment: It's giving me the "bad request" as a response because I'm neglecting body to send.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is a valid request for the service you are calling, but to set headers and body and send a request it would look like this:

```
HttpClient clientTest = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,url);

httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(xml.Document.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.citrix.sessionstate+xml");
httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("CitrixAuth", "H4sIAAAAAAAEAK1X2Y6jyBL9lZLnEbnZt1J");

var response = await clientTest.SendAsync(httpRequest);
```

If you get a 400 Bad Request it because **what** you are sending is not appropriate for the API, not because of **how** you are sending it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was not sending the body content in the StringContent class. That was a reason i was getting the bad request response. Thanks for the resolution.